# Get 'special' folder icons in sidebar after Music, Pictures moved to 2nd drive

Tags: finder, folders, icon, sidebar

I moved my Pictures and Music folders off my boot drive (now SSD) and onto my second larger drive. Creating shortcuts to these new locations in the sidebar creates standard folder icons rather than the original special ones (eg musical note for Music). So it seems that Mavericks only creates the 'special' icons if it recognises those folders in the Home folder.

Is there a way to trick the OS into thinking these are the 'real' music and pictures folders, so it creates those picture icons again? I saw other answers talking about symlinks, but I haven't used symlinks here (I don't know how to do that). Maybe that is the way to go if it does create the result I am seeking?

Comment: You could consider moving your entire homefolder and move the homefolder location (on your useraccount) to the new location. Everything should be alright then.

Comment: Rob, thanks, yep that would work if I wanted to move entire Home folder, but I don't. I'd like to keep some elements of home folder (eg iTunes Library) on the SSD to take advantage of it's speed, yet store my iTunes media for example off on the slower, but larger, HDD.

Comment: J.D. Can you point me toward directions on how to achieve the two drive setup you have?  I am going to install a SSD, and I want the music, video, pictures folders to remain on the HDD as well.

Comment: @traggatmot - It's a while ago since I did it, here's a description I found which I think is the way to go and I will do it this way for a friend's MBP I'm about to do the same with: http://blog.macsales.com/24915-splitting-your-data-an-alternative-to-fusion